# Как из Intellij IDEA профилировать приложение, стоящее на удаленном WildFly с помощью JProfiler

Tags: intellij-idea, wildfly, profiler

У меня есть Intellij Idea 2020, JProfiler и плагин JProfiler для IDEA. На удаленном сервере стоит WildFly 15, на котором крутится приложение.
Сейчас в standalone.conf прописаны ключи для подключения по jmx для jconsole

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9010
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Я хочу профилировать приложение с помощью JProfiler из Идеи, но нигде четкой инструкции не нашла, как подключить профилирование.
Насколько я понимаю, нужно распокавать какую-то часть JProfiler на сервер и добавить ключи в standalone.conf для JVM?
Если напишите пошагово, буду очень благодарна

Answer (score 0):

У JMX довольно хитро с сетью. Он использует рандомные порты, которые сложно прокинуть.

Если ресурсов в инфраструктуре много, можно сделать виртуальную рабочую станцию для разбора сложных случаев, и ходить на нее по Spice протоколу.

На ней может быть еще (временно конечно) много памяти для разбора больших heap-dump-ов.

Можно еще посмотреть в сторону VPN.

Возможно у JProfiler есть свое, специфичное решение этих вопросов.